# Nsis Script : Reading from registry key value in NSIS script fails

Tags: windows, registry, nsis

I am creating my installer with multiple dependency in that, after my exe get install successfully it will go for re-install. But while reading from registry its giving nothing, still entry is present in registry.
To debug this issue I am reading my registry entry its showing correct value. But when I am running again my exe it giving nothing.

"This problem is coming when I am installing my exe dependency then my exe. When dependency is already installed this problem is not coming.
Please help me

code :

```
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "UninstallString" 
StrCmp $R0 "" init.install
```

each time $R0 value is "", but in same path entry is present. Help me to debug this issue.

Comment: Did you check if ${PRODUCT_NAME} is defined? Do you use [SetRegView](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/SetRegView.md)?

Comment: Yes Product name is defined and my entry is created in registry but not able to read when I am running my installer again after successful installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may occur because NSIS reads from wow6432node on x64 OS.
It reads from win32 view by default because NSIS installer is win32 process.
SetRegView 64 may be called before reading in that case.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SetRegView

Comment: Thanks for the help I have added setregView in nsis script its working.